# Can clonezilla image a recovery partition?

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla, windows-re

I am trying to image an entire disk but the last partition (the windows recovery partition) failed. How can I tell if this is a disk error or some sort of copy protection mechanism?

I'm using an asus laptop if that's any help.

Comment: There is no copy protection on HDDs. How exactly has it failed?

Comment: it says that the disk has bad sectors and that it may be physical damage. Also to use the --rescue option to restore as much data as possible.

Answer (score 3):

As gronostaj stated already, there is no "copy protection mechanism".
The only issue that could be is the use of a "host protected area". So far I have not heard about a HPA for recovery purposes.

Run smartmontools or Crystaldiskinfo and look at the raw number for the attribute "pending sectors".

If this is greater than zero you have a quick indication on read errors on your disk.
For detailed information where your read error(s) is/are located run ddrescue under Linux und use the mapfile attribute. The mapfile will indicate the error location.

Comment: I'll have a look at those programs and report. Thanks.